# How to pass DB records as JSON data from Spring MVC application to Android Application using RESTful Web services

Tags: android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I do have an Spring MVC web application integrated with PostgreSQL DB. Also I do have an android application. I am in the process of implementing RESTful web services between android application and Spring MVC Web application in such a way that Spring MVC web server will send data in JSON format to a specific URL and the same will be read by Android application for further processing. If my question is unclear pls do ask for more so that I will try giving more info on it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you look at [spring-data-rest project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest) in spring-projects?

Comment: i checked that. but it could be better in which of those projects is related with connection of  Android appln + Spring MVC web appln using JSON/REST.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you need at client side (Android) some Spring-powered feature that can receive and handle JSON by REST, and on server side youd need Spring-powered feature that can produce JSON and send if by REST. So, as i mentioned before, at server you can use spring-data-rest (or Spring MVC if you want complicated data handling), and at client side you can use Spriing RestTemplate [http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/). Also you can use JSON schema approach to establish JSON protocol. Hope this helps.